# how to push the json into an array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I want to add json in this format what I do for this

```
student{
      nmae:testing
    marks:[{
            subject:{
                class1:2,
                name:testing,
                number:56,
                grade:b,
            },
    {
            subject:{
                class1:2,
                name:testg,
                number:54,
                grade:b,
            }
        }],
}
```

I was use

```
db.students.update({"name":"testing"},{$push:{"marks":{"subject":{"class1":1,name:"math","number":12,"garde":"B"}}}});
```

but it was not work or getting an error.
I don't know where I'm wrong please help me

Comment: What about posting the error?

Comment: this is error "code" : 16837,
  "errmsg" : "The field 'marks' must be an array but is of type Object in document {_id: ObjectId('55b38136c645304214249b68')}"

Comment: can you please make this query and post the result? `db.students.find({_id: ObjectId('55b38136c645304214249b68')})`

Comment: after the quering the result is    {
 "_id" : ObjectId("55b38136c645304214249b68"),
 "name" : "testing",
 "rollnumber" : "12345",
 "password" : "testing",
 "issuebook" : [ ],
 "marks" : {
  "subject" : {
   "class1" : 1,
   "name" : "math",
   "number" : 12,
   "garde" : "B"
  }
 },
 "__v" : 0,
 "status" : "Active",
 "status1" : "Active"
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the resulting document, you have an object as the value of `marks` fields:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55b38136c645304214249b68"), 
    "name" : "testing", 
    "rollnumber" : "12345", 
    "password" : "testing", 
    "issuebook" : [], 
    "marks" : {
        "subject" : {
            "class1" : 1, 
            "name" : "math", 
            "number" : 12, 
            "garde" : "B"
        } 
    }, 
    "__v" : 0, 
    "status" : "Active", 
    "status1" : "Active"
}
```

So you get the error.

Do the following to recover:

```
db.student.remove({_id: ObjectId("55b38136c645304214249b68")})
db.student.insert({
        "_id" : ObjectId("55b38136c645304214249b68"), 
        "name" : "testing", 
        "rollnumber" : "12345", 
        "password" : "testing", 
        "issuebook" : [], 
        "marks" : [
            {
                "subject" : {
                    "class1" : 1, 
                    "name" : "math", 
                    "number" : 12, 
                    "garde" : "B"
                }
            }
        ] 
        "__v" : 0, 
        "status" : "Active", 
        "status1" : "Active"
    }
)
```